# Does kali distro not use /etc/environments file?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, environment-variables, kali-linux

I appended a path to /etc/environments file and now it is like so:

```
mindaugas@Kali:~$ cat /etc/environment | tr ":" "\n"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/sbin"
```

I logged out and logged in again. But my `$PATH` did not change:

```
mindaugas@Kali:~$ echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/games
/usr/games
```

Performing same steps in ubuntu 14.04 changed the `$PATH`.

I'm curiuos - why is that?

Answer (score 1):

On linux, the reading of `/etc/environment` is usually done by the
**pam_env.so** module during login. This module may not be installed on a
minimal system, or may be configured not to read the /etc file, or it may
not be configured in /etc/pam.d/* to be called during the login process.
See `man pam_env pam`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no obligation coded into most shells to load `/etc/environment`.

Which exact files the shell looks for and what order it attempts to load them depends on the actual shell you use, but in general only `/etc/shellnamerc` and `~/.shellnamerc` are ones you can absolutely count on being read, usually in that order. Consult your preferred shell's manpage for the specifics.

What happens in your particular case in ubuntu is that your preferred shell loads its config file in `/etc/` and/or the one provided for your account at creation by way of `/etc/skel/`, and either of those config files told it to look for `/etc/environment` and load its contents if it exists.

Yes, this is a handy feature in some circumstances, but it's not an universal one... And frankly, it *can't* be one because different shells can have different ways of setting environment variables; a `/etc/environment` sourced for Bourne-type shells (`bash`, `sh`, `dash`) will not work for C shells (`csh`, `tcsh`), for example.

**TL;DR**: `/etc/environment` is an optional feature that's common but not universal. Kali's lack of it is not a bug.

Comment: `/etc/environment` isn't read by a shell, it's read by the login program before it starts a shell, [if `pam_env` is included in the PAM stack](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211787).